# How to use the constraints and sizes of other widgets during the build phase

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make sure I cover all cases

1. A Parent widget reads (and possibly uses) a child's size or constraints
2. A Child widget reads (and possibly uses) a parent's size or constraints
3. A Child widget reads (and possibly uses) another child's size or constraints

The solution seems to be to...

1. Let the build phase run
2. Then the size and constraints of the widget I want to retreive data from are built
3. Then I interrupt the regular sequence of phases (so the draw Frame function does not run)
4. Then rerun the build phase with the data I now have
5. And allow the frame to draw

Problem is I don't know how to do this

I posted a much more specific question earlier relating to this and I got a couple of responses, layout builder, custom multi child layout, and custom single child layout...

But these are for very specific circumstances

The Layout builder builds a widget tree that can depend on the parent widget's size. So It only handles case 2

And the other two have the limitation that the size of the parent cannot depend on the size of the child. So it seems to imply that it only handles case 2.

So what other solutions are out there?

The rect getter plugin works but does not interupt the draw Frame so there is a frame of stutter
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rect_getter

The after layout plugin I have not tried yet but it seems like the same issue occurs because it says it runs after the first frame 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/after_layout

Any help is appreciated! 
I would hate to have to just live with using work arounds constantly :/

Comment: Both `rect_getter` and `after_layout` sounds like unneeded plugins. The things they bring are both one liner out of the box

Comment: Yeah you don't need them but they are easy and concise to reference (like I did here)

Comment: Your use cases seem strange and like they would pretty easily allow for a "deadlock" in layout...  Can you provide a specific, detailed example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Widgets can't do such thing on purpose. 
A Widget should **never** depend on the size and position or *anything*. Not even their children.

If you ever face a situation where you need to, `LayoutBuilder` should be fine most of the time.

If it's not, what you want to create isn't a `Widget`. But a `RenderObject` instead, one of the lower layer of flutter.

Widgets such as `Center`, `Stack` or `Column` are in fact computed using `RenderObject`.

Comment: Layout builder still has limitations so it doesn't cover all the cases. But yes I know how to access the renderobject (that's what rect getter does) but I don't know how to stop the layout phase from triggering the next phase which then triggers the draw Frame function in the last phase. So I want to access that render object data but i Want to do it and stop the frame from running... So in essence for that frame this is how the phases should go... Build layout build layout... Draw frame... The build and layout process is repeated until you grab all the data required

Comment: I'm not saying access Render Object. I mean coding a subclass of RenderObject and using it on a widget.

Comment: Perhaps it's my unfamiliarity with the system... But I don't understand how that would help... I need to get the render object information (as viewable in the render tree) but that is calculated in the build phase

Comment: Widgets don't size or position anything at all. RenderObjects do. It's RenderObjects that contain all of the layout logic. Widgets are just here to make usage of RenderObjects easier by restricting some usages such as depending on your parent/child size. But RenderObjects themselves don't have such limitation

Comment: Simply open the code of say `Stack` or `Align`. You'll see that in fact they are doing almost nothing beside instantiating a `RenderStack` or `RenderAlign`.

Comment: I'm sorry... I inspected Stack and Align but I have no idea how to use it to do what I need... It's probably asking too much but If possible... could you make examples showing each case?!... like allow the build method to calculated the size given the constraints... and use that size before the next draw Frame function runs?!

Comment: Too much indeed. Consider instead making a new question stating "what you need". These use cases are too broad to provide a finite answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of rect getter plugin , and I quite intrested in your qestion.

Yes , as other guys said, I think flutter is a very flexible UI framwork, so we do not need know a widget's actual size in most case. But when I tried to write a anime effect whitch simulate open a book, I found it was necessary to know a 'Card''s rect information, and finally I found the way to get a rect from a rended object from the source code of [heros.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/heroes.dart). As a result , it became the rect getter plugin whitch you known.
[image: flutter_openbookeffect]

In fact, maybe I'm facing the same problem with you, because I want to write a 'Masonry' layout like [this](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb), so I should know the previous items's rect infomation to decide where the current item should be drawn.

My solution is :
1.Wrap the child widget by rect_getter, build the layout normally first;
2.And then, use timer to get the child's rect information immediately after build complete;
3.Call setState() to rebuild the layout, and use children's rect information to calculate each child's constraintbox in viewport.

Code fragment (NOT finished) :
[image: code fragment]

and current progress：
[image]

My codes can found [here](http://debuggerx.com:19998/explore/repos), but they were so terrible and commented use Chinese, so I don't think you will want to read them.

Comment: Yes @debuggerx this is exactly what I was doing but I was getting a frame of "stutter" for each dependancy... This is because after each build phase the natural progression of phases continues and draws the visual frame... Then set state is called and build runs again... This whole process occurs for each dependancy... So suppose you had A depends on B, that depends on C, That depends on D... you would have 3 "stutter frames"... So what I want to do is find a way to avoid this... Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but still pops up in a lot of searches.

Building arbitrary widgets based on the size of another widget is very difficult problem to solve, even with a custom Element and RenderObject.

I wrote the [boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy) package, which has a feature that allows you to inflate arbitrary widgets at layout time.

The following example is a Text widget that displays the dimensions of one of its siblings:

[image]

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomBoxy(
      delegate: MyBoxyDelegate(),
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyBoxyDelegate extends BoxyDelegate {
  @override
  Size layout() {
    // Lay out the container first.
    final container = children.single;
    final containerSize = container.layout(constraints);

    // Inflate a Text widget based on the containers size.
    final text = inflate(
      Text('^ $containerSize'),
      id: #text,
    );
    final textSize = text.layout(constraints);

    // Position the text below the container.
    text.position(Offset(0, containerSize.height));

    return Size(
      max(containerSize.width, textSize.width),
      containerSize.height + textSize.height,
    );
  }
}
```