# How do I get the Yellow Container To Expand and Fill The Rest of the Space that its Purple Parents Has Available

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is a specific example that requires case 2 and case 3 from this other post
[How to use the constraints and sizes of other widgets during the build phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779684/how-to-use-the-constraints-and-sizes-of-other-widgets-during-the-build-phase?noredirect=1#comment88568510_50779684)

-------------------------BASIC HEIRARCHY-------------------------

main [FLEX]
child 1: red (expanded)
child 2: purple (non expanded, but it obeys its min constraint) [FLEX]
------child 1: green (non expanded, works as expected)
------child 2: yellow (I would like it to fill the rest of the space that purple has available but the system wont let me just use expanded)

-------------------------GOAL-------------------------

I want the yellow box to fill the rest of the space available inside the purple box.

NOTE: the very specific combination of widgets that don't allow me to wrap the yellow container in an expanded widget

-------------------------WHY I CANT USE EXPANDED-------------------------

If I wrap the yellow widget in an expanded it throws an error... here is why...

in that particular case I have 2 containers inside of a flex
child 1(of main): the red one is expanding so...
child 2(of main): the purple one tries to shrink wrap its children and take the least amount of space as possible but technically it has no max constraints (only min constraints which is why there is still some purple visible)

the purple child is also a flex and has 2 children, since the purple flex is trying to shrink wrap its children it will tell its children to do the same
child 1(of purple): the green container does this and its fine because I want it to do this but...
child 2(of purple): I want the yellow container to fill the space purple has created with its min-width param

problem is that the yellow containers purple parent is telling it to shrink wrap its children (as explained above) but then if I wrap it in an expanded widget you are telling the yellow container to expand or in other words not shrink wrap its children... and well the yellow container can both shrink wrap and not shrink wrap its children
so you get an error

So...
I need to know the calculated width of the purple container
then the calculated width of the green container
then the width of my yellow container would be
yellow.width = purple.width - green.width

-------------------------CODE OUTPUT-------------------------

[this shows the output of the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqo0U.png)

[image: this shows the current output vs the desired output]

-------------------------MAIN.DART-------------------------

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'materialSheet.dart';

    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      final appTitle = 'Material Sheets Demo';

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: new MaterialSheet(
            app: new Text("kill \n\n me plz"),
            sheet: new Icon(Icons.keyboard),
            attachment: new Icon(Icons.attachment),
            position: sheetPosition.right,
            placement: attachmentPlacement.inside,
            sheetMin: 125.0,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

-------------------------MATERIALSHEET.DART-------------------------

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//-------------------------Enumerations-------------------------

enum sheetPosition { top, right, bottom, left }
enum sheetType { modal, persistent }
enum attachmentPlacement { inside, outside }

class MaterialSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  //-------------------------Parameters-------------------------

  final Widget app;
  final Widget sheet;
  final Widget attachment;

  final sheetPosition position;
  final sheetType type; //TODO add in the scrim behind the thing
  final attachmentPlacement placement;

  final double sheetMin; //TODO
  final double sheetMax; //TODO
  final double percentBeforeOpen; //TODO
  final bool autoOpenIndicator; //TODO
  final double percentBeforeClose; //TODO
  final bool autoCloseIndicator; //TODO

  final bool vertiScroll; //TODO
  final bool horiScroll; //TODO

  final bool swipeToOpen; //TODO
  final bool swipeToClose; //TODO

  MaterialSheet(
      {@required this.app,
      @required this.sheet,
      this.attachment,
      this.position: sheetPosition.bottom,
      this.type: sheetType.modal,
      this.placement: attachmentPlacement.inside,
      this.sheetMin,
      this.sheetMax,
      this.percentBeforeOpen: .5,
      this.autoOpenIndicator: true,
      this.percentBeforeClose: .5,
      this.autoCloseIndicator: true,
      this.vertiScroll: false,
      this.horiScroll: false,
      this.swipeToOpen: true,
      this.swipeToClose: true});

  //-------------------------Helper Code-------------------------k

  BoxConstraints _calcBoxConstraints(bool fullWidth) {
    if (sheetMin == null && sheetMax == null)
      return new BoxConstraints();
    else {
      if (sheetMin != null && sheetMax != null) {
        if (fullWidth) //we only care for height
          return new BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: sheetMin,
            maxHeight: sheetMax,
          );
        else //we only care for width
          return new BoxConstraints(minWidth: sheetMin, maxWidth: sheetMax);
      } else {
        if (sheetMin != null) {
          //we only have min
          if (fullWidth) //we only care for height
            return new BoxConstraints(minHeight: sheetMin);
          else //we only care for width
            return new BoxConstraints(minWidth: sheetMin);
        } else {
          //we only have max
          if (fullWidth) //we only care for h`eight
            return new BoxConstraints(maxHeight: sheetMax);
          else //we only care for width
            return new BoxConstraints(maxWidth: sheetMax);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //-------------------------Actual Code-------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool isWidthMax =
        (position == sheetPosition.bottom || position == sheetPosition.top);

    //-----Create the Widgets and Initially calculate Sizes

    print("before test");
    Scaffold testScaff = theSheet(isWidthMax, context);
    print("after test");

    //-----Apply Size constraints as needed

    Align testAl = new Align();

    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        //---------------Contains your Application
        new Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          body: app,
        ),
        //---------------Contains the Sheet
        theSheet(isWidthMax, context),
      ],
    );
  }

  Scaffold theSheet(bool isWidthMax, BuildContext context) {

    Scaffold generatedScaffold = genScaff(isWidthMax);

    EdgeInsetsGeometry padCheck = (((generatedScaffold.body as Flex).children[0] as Flexible).child as Container).padding;

    print("value " + padCheck.toString());

    return generatedScaffold;
  }

  Scaffold genScaff(bool isWidthMax) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Flex(
        direction: (isWidthMax) ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
        //ONLY relevant if position is top or bottom
        textDirection: (position == sheetPosition.right)
            ? TextDirection.ltr
            : TextDirection.rtl,
        //ONLY relevant if position is left or right
        verticalDirection: (position == sheetPosition.top)
            ? VerticalDirection.up
            : VerticalDirection.down,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.3),
                color: Colors.red,
              )),
          new ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: _calcBoxConstraints(isWidthMax),
            child: new Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              child: new Flex(
                direction: (isWidthMax) ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
                //ONLY relevant if position is top or bottom
                textDirection: (position == sheetPosition.right)
                    ? (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? TextDirection.rtl
                    : TextDirection.ltr
                    : (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? TextDirection.ltr
                    : TextDirection.rtl,
                //ONLY relevant if position is left or right
                verticalDirection: (position == sheetPosition.top)
                    ? (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? VerticalDirection.down
                    : VerticalDirection.up
                    : (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? VerticalDirection.up
                    : VerticalDirection.down,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    child: sheet,
                  ),
                  new Flexible(
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: new Container(
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      child: (attachment != null) ? attachment : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Question unclear. Can you provide a visual example of the desired behavior ? Even if it's manual drawing.

Comment: great idea I will do so right now

Comment: @RémiRousselet I added the details you requested... any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your inner `Row` into a `IntrinsicWidth` to enforce it to take the least amount of space possible based on it's content.

Thanks to that, you can now wrap a child of that inner row into an `Expanded` without having exception.

[image]

```
 new Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    new ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: new BoxConstraints(minWidth: 100.0),
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: new IntrinsicWidth(
          child: new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                color: Colors.cyan,
                child: new Icon(Icons.title),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Icon(Icons.theaters)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I tried using intristics width and height but I realize now that I was using it incorrectly. Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the following changes:

1.- Replace the ConstrainedBox() with a SizedBox()

2.- Replace the last Flexible() with an Expanded(). Flexible adapts itself to the size of the container. Try it by removing the container child.

3.- And finally switch the green Container() and the yellow Container(). Otherwise the green one gets expanded.

This is the working code for the Scaffold:

```
  Scaffold genScaff(bool isWidthMax) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Flex(
        direction: (isWidthMax) ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
        //ONLY relevant if position is top or bottom
        textDirection: (position == sheetPosition.right)
            ? TextDirection.ltr
            : TextDirection.rtl,
        //ONLY relevant if position is left or right
        verticalDirection: (position == sheetPosition.top)
            ? VerticalDirection.up
            : VerticalDirection.down,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.3),
                color: Colors.red,
              )),
          new SizedBox(
            width: 125.0, // Do your calculations based on isWidthMax
            height: double.infinity,
            //constraints: _calcBoxConstraints(isWidthMax),
            child: new Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              child: new Flex(
                direction: (isWidthMax) ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
                //ONLY relevant if position is top or bottom
                textDirection: (position == sheetPosition.right)
                    ? (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? TextDirection.rtl
                    : TextDirection.ltr
                    : (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? TextDirection.ltr
                    : TextDirection.rtl,
                //ONLY relevant if position is left or right
                verticalDirection: (position == sheetPosition.top)
                    ? (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? VerticalDirection.down
                    : VerticalDirection.up
                    : (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                    ? VerticalDirection.up
                    : VerticalDirection.down,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Container(
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                      child: sheet,
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    child: (attachment != null) ? attachment : null,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the result

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the attempt but here you are directly setting width which doesn't really help me... I have a min and max width... but if the width is in between those two values it would be calculated depending on the content inside the container... 
don't worry about it though, remi's solution works