# How to use the sizes of other widgets before the widget tree is drawn ? [with Example]

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This Shows all 3 cases discussed in this other post with a simple example.
[How to use the constraints and sizes of other widgets during the build phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779684/how-to-use-the-constraints-and-sizes-of-other-widgets-during-the-build-phase)

NOTE:

1. I know that this is weird
2. I know that if used improperly this could create layouts that are never drawn
3. Just Reading Constraints is not enough because sometimes the constraints don't exist (like in this particular case)

GOAL:
**Get what is drawn on screen to stabilize after 0 ReBuilds (or 1 build) instead of 2 ReBuilds**

CURRENT PROCESS:

1. Build 1 [image: Build 1]
2. Build 2 [image: Build 2]
3. Build 3 [image: Build 3]

when ("automaticReBuilding " == true) => the system automatically rebuilds itself depending on the quantity of dependancies (this is determined by you)
[the fact that automatic rebuilding runs the build function multiple times is what creates the stutter problem I have referred to now and in previous posts]

when ("automaticReBuilding" == false) => the system waits for you to rebuild things manually

//--------------------------------------------------CODE START

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

//Desired Behavior on FIRST build (It should not take 3)
//CASE 1 (parent uses child size) : eye.width = vane.width * 10
//CASE 2 (child uses parent size) : pupil.width = iris.width / 2
//CASE 3: (child uses sibling size) : iris.width = vane.width * 5

//Desired Sizes (can be read from Render Tree in Flutter Inspector) [in original config of 4 letters]
//vane = 30
//pupil = 75
//iris = 150
//eye = 300

//NOTE: that vane width (aka size) is not determined until we see what is inside of it

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StateFull();
  }
}

class StateFull extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StateFullState createState() => new _StateFullState();
}

var vaneKey = new GlobalKey();
var vaneWidth;
var irisKey = new GlobalKey();
var irisWidth;

class _StateFullState extends State<StateFull> {

  //NOTE: change this to either run the rebuild in one shot or slowly see the progression
  bool automaticReBuilding = false;
  //NOTE: this starts here because the first build method isn't technically a rebuild
  int timesReBuilt = -1;
  //NOTE: this is set MANUALLY given the dependencies between your widgets
  //In this particular case C relies on B which relies on A
  //so (first) I get the size of A, (second) I use the size of A to get B, (third) i use the size of B to get C
  //which comes down to 3 rebuilds
  int requiredBuildsPerChange = 3;
  int timesBuilt = 0;

  rebuild(){
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  rebuildAsync() async{
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    timesReBuilt++;

    if(automaticReBuilding){
      timesBuilt++;
      print("build #" + timesBuilt.toString());
      if(timesBuilt < requiredBuildsPerChange)
        rebuildAsync();
      else
        timesBuilt = 0;
    }

    var complexWidget = complexRelationshipWidget();

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: '3 Cases Test',
      home: new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        body: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: complexWidget,
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => (automaticReBuilding == false) ? rebuild() : null,
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.update),
                    new Text("Manual ReBuilds\nOR\nAutomatic Frame Stutter\n$timesReBuilt", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  Container complexRelationshipWidget() {

    vaneWidth = vaneKey?.currentContext?.findRenderObject()?.semanticBounds?.size?.width;
    irisWidth = irisKey?.currentContext?.findRenderObject()?.semanticBounds?.size?.width;

    return new Container( //-----EYE-----
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
        width: vaneWidth == null ? null : vaneWidth * 10,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container( //-----VANE-----
              key: vaneKey,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: new Text("vane"),
            ),
            new Container( //-----IRIS-----
              key: irisKey,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
              width: vaneWidth == null ? null : vaneWidth * 5,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: new Container( //-----PUPIL
                decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
                width: irisWidth == null ? null : irisWidth / 2,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------CODE END

Comment: Why do you need everything to be dynamically sized here ? You could statically drawn widget with a `scale` property. Which would do the same thing in the end.

Comment: This still doesn't make it clear why you can't do what @RémiRousselet is suggesting.  You should be able to scale or transform your existing widgets however you want - you should not be depending on multiple build passes, you will not get good performance.  Why can you not just determine the initial seed width ahead of time?

Comment: I can't determine the initial seed width because that depends on the content... In this case the width of the "vane" container might be hello, or hi, etc so that might change the seed width... But that seed width is calculated after you go back up the tree... You are correct tho if I could have this seed size calculated at the begining, this would be very easy... The question is, is there a way to do that without displaying a frame... And yes you are correct Dan it does affect performance... But I am willing to take that hit in exchange for more flexibility and options when building unique UIs